# Combined mass of binary stars

Tags: astrophysics, orbital-mechanics, binary-star

This is Question 17 from USAAAO Practice Round 2015. The answer is D. It would be best if someone can detail out the workings.

> In a nearby star system, two stars are seen to orbit each other every
>   8 years. At their closest, the stars are 2” apart. At their furthest,
>   they are 18” apart. If a parallax of 0.5” is observed for the star
>   system, what is its combined mass in solar masses? Assume an
>   inclination of 90 degrees.
>
> - a. 0.5
> - b. 1
> - c. 2
> - d. 4
> - e. 8

What I got so far:

- Distance to system: 2pc (6.171e16 m)
- Minimum separation: 5.98e11 m
- Maximum separation: 5.38e12 m
- Relative semimajor axis: 2.99e12 m (20AU)
- Combined mass: 125 solar masses

Comment: I got a combined mass of 125 too,  care to show your working?

Comment: James K, after I have the semi major axis, I calculate the mass using Kepler’s Third Law. I think there must be some typo in the data given because we got the same answer. Thanks for your help :)